# square root in \draw (0.707,1/2)--(1,1/2);

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\draw (0.707,1/2)--(1,1/2);
```

I wanted $\sqrt{1/2}$ instead of $0.707$. Is there a way to write $\sqrt{1/2}$ in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\x{sqrt(1/2)}
\draw (\x,1/2)--(1,1/2);
```

Comment: One could also do it without an intermediate assignment by enclosing the computation within a `{}` as `\draw ({sqrt(1/2)},1/2)--(1,1/2);`

Comment: @PeterGrill, I didn't know, because I usually use parameters in my tikz drawings. But it's good to know, thanks!!